# jQuery append replaces image with img

Tags: jquery, image, svg

So I'm generating a svg and in svg there are `<image>` tags however whenever I append the `<image>` tag, it gets replaced with `<img>`

http://jsfiddle.net/d4s4p3az/

```
$('body').prepend('<image></image><br>');

$('body').append('img tags: '+$('body').children('img').length+'<br>');
$('body').append('image tags: '+$('body').children('image').length);
```

What's up with that.

Is this a jQuery thing? I've tried it in chrome and safari with the same results.

**Edit:**

Ended up with this function to append svg code to svg where the 1st argument is a jQuery object of the svg and the 2nd argument is the svg code to append.

```
function appendToSVG(svg,text){
    text = svg.html()+text;
    attributes = svg[0].attributes;

    var attrs = '';
    for (var i=0; i <= attributes.length-1; i++){
       attrs += attributes[i].name+'="'+attributes[i].value+'" ';       
    }
    svg.after('<svg '+attrs+'>'+text+'</svg>');
    svg.remove();
}
```

Comment: It looks like the browser does it. Try the same thing with raw Javascript: `div.innerHTML = "<image></image>"`

Comment: Looks like `<image>` is only allowed inside `<svg>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `image` element in HTML, neither in [in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1) nor [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html). I expect browsers are just handling a common misspelling.

`image` is an [**SVG** element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/eltindex.html), so you can't put it directly in `body`, it has to be within an SVG context. E.g.: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4s4p3az/2/)

```
$('body').prepend('<svg><image></image></svg><br>');

$('body').append('img tags: '+$('body').find('img').length+'<br>');
$('body').append('image tags: '+$('body').find('image').length);
```

...which gives us:

```
img tags: 0
image tags: 1
```

Comment: The same behaviour happends when instering it into a svg where it 'breaks' my code. Here's the part that I use and doesn't work.

`.children('svg').prepend('<clipPath id="'+id+'_"><rect rx="'+roundness+'" ry="'+roundness+'" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#'+id+')">'+$('<image width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" xlink:href="'+url+'"></image>')+'</g>');`

Comment: I suspect if you stepped into the (unminified) jQuery source when calling `prepend`, eventually you'd find it first instantiating those elements (in an HTML context), and *then* prepending them to the `svg` element. So the browser thinks it's dealing with HTML, not SVG, as of when jQuery creates the elements.

Comment: @MatthewAbrman: Glad that helped. And I just did the stepping into `prepend` thing, and sure enough, it creates the elements in your string in an HTML context before appending them to the `svg` element.

Comment: I'm no good with javascript, is there a way I could append to a svg element with plain javascript? use something like $('.my-svg')[0].appendToSvg('text-to-append');

Comment: You could also append that <image> tag by using the parseSVG() function shown in the above link. That's an alternate method just in case you need to append it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case when you do:

```
$('body').prepend('<image></image>');
```

jQuery will try to convert the string you try to append to a dom element before appending it, but image is not an official tag (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) so your browser will create an  tag because it thought this is what you want

To force the browser to create the tag you want you should tell jQuery that what you want is an custom  tag using this code:

```
var $image = $('<image>');

$('body').prepend($image);
```

this is ok for browser that let you create custom html elements like chrome and firefox, but this wont work in IE, have a look at this updated fiddle (will tell you "image tags 1" in chrome but still "image tags 0" in IE):

http://jsfiddle.net/d4s4p3az/1/

So the solution is to create a w3c conform  tag using the svg image namespace:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function onDomLoad() {

    $('svg').append('<image>');
    $('svg').append($('<image>'));

    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
    $('svg').append(svg);

    $('body').append('img tags: '+$('svg').children('img').length+'<br>');
    $('body').append('image tags: '+$('svg').children('image').length);

});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d4s4p3az/11/

A good article about manipulating SVG images using javascript can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/surviving-the-zombie-apocalypse-manipulating-svg-with-javascript/

Maybe in your case what would be usefull is to use a javascript library like svg.js: http://www.svgjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

I think by creating jQuery selector you can do this:

```
var image = $('<image></image>');
$('body').prepend(image);
```

Comment: That does work, do you know if there is a way I could do that with a longer script? When I tried that with setting some attributes to the image and prepended it it just did [object Object].